# Can I connect to stackoverflow chat with a proper IRC client?

Tags: support, chat

Is it possible to use an IRC client to connect to the chat servers of Stack Overflow?

Or is this only a web chat?

Comment: If you want to use protocols like irc, you need a DeLorean and a flux-capacitor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can not connect with an IRC client to the chat servers of Stack Exchange, including the ones on Stack Overflow.

There have been [various requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=irc) over on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59760/irc-access-for-the-chat) to get something like that implemented/supported but so far none of those have been followed by an release of such functionality.

Your might take a look if there is something over at [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/search?q=chat+client) but the initial search doesn't give much hope.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I kind of expected that. I'll look at what the jabber bot can do, but don't have high expectations for it.